# Export table to Excel have both < U+F70A> string and Thai string in r

Tags: r, pdf, encoding, utf-8, thai

I have used pdf_text to read pdf file and split for making them to the table
This is my code and the result (have many < U+F70A> instead of some characters in my language) : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNFLY.png)

```
> txt14_16 <- pdf_text(".pdf") 

> data<-(txt14_16[100]) 
> df <- data %>% 
  read_lines()%>% 
  grep('^\\s{5}\\w|^\\s{1}\\w',., value = TRUE)  
> out <- data.table(do.call( rbind, strsplit( df, '\\s{3,}' ) ))
```

I have tried to use this code

```
out1<-out%>%
stri_replace_all_regex("<U\\+([[:alnum:]]+)>", "\\\\u$1") %>% 
stri_unescape_unicode() %>% 
stri_enc_toutf8()
```

and it was good (it will appear all the string in my language in the R result  without < U+F70A> )in the list as result but i can not export them to Excel,text,csv. When i export them they will appear with < U+F70A>

So, i want to export them to Excel without < U+F70A>.

Comment: UTF8 is the page you see right now. SO is an ASP.NET site that sends text encoded in UTF8 which is why I can write Αυτό Εδώ knowing it will appear without issues. There's no "normal language", nor anything to change

Comment: What does the *actual* text look like? What does `< U+F70A> format` mean? Those aren't Unicode characters, those are a sequence of 6 ASCII characters, 8 if you count the angle brackets. Is that how the text actually looks? Or is that how the tool you used displays non-ASCII characters, probably because it lacks Unicode fonts?

Comment: In any case, Excel files use UTF8 encoding. An Excel file (xlsx) is a zip package that contains XML files, which in turn use UTF8 encoding.

Comment: As for replacing, you can't replace what isn't there. If `U+F70A` is the way your tool displays non-ASCII characters, there's nothing to replace. If the text contains those 6 ASCII characters, the code that generates the text has a bug

Comment: i have attached the link of result.

Comment: Post the *text*, the code that produces and reads it, not the results of the replacement code. That replacement will never work simply because there are no such sequences in the text

Comment: The bug is in the code that produces or reads the text. `F70A` belongs to a [private use area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas), a block of characters that have no assignment and definitely don't belong to any language

Comment: The code in the screenshot tries to read text from a PDF file. First, PDF is *not* a text format. It can contain other info, including glyph, color information, images, formatting etc. Text elements can appear in unexpected locations and not necessarily in the way they are displayed. Any attempt to read text *can* return unexpected characters.

Comment: and why i use second code ,the result in r is all my language that i want without any < U+F70A>.